# Scrollview only while keyboard appear

Tags: android, android-layout, uiscrollview

I'm looking for an answer what should I do to prepare static layout ( without ScrollView, because when I put as a root ScrollView, then my LinearLayout is bigger than screen size, without scrollview, linearlayout is perfect ), so I have a form with 5 edittexts, and when I click on once of them, keyboard appear and now I need scroll on this form. I tried use ScrollView, android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" and much more, but nothing works.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#aa000000">


<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false" android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/blueBackground"
        android:background="#aa000000"

/>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                  android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:src="@drawable/applogo"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_height="60dp" android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
        />
        <TextView
                android:text="Text1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:textColor="@color/apptheme_color" android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="35dp" android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
        />
        <TextView
                android:text="Text2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/numberTextView" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@color/apptheme_color" android:textSize="24sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
        />
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/edit1"
                android:background="@drawable/blueborder"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" android:layout_marginRight="25dp" android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" android:paddingBottom="10dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Edit1"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/edit2"
                android:background="@drawable/blueborder"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" android:layout_marginRight="25dp" android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" android:paddingBottom="10dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Edit2"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/edi3"
                android:background="@drawable/blueborder"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" android:layout_marginRight="25dp" android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" android:paddingBottom="10dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Edit3"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/edit4"
                android:background="@drawable/blueborder"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" android:layout_marginRight="25dp" android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" android:paddingBottom="10dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Edit4"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/edit5"
                android:background="@drawable/blueborder"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" android:layout_marginRight="25dp" android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" android:paddingBottom="20dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="3.33"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" android:hint="Notatka" android:lines="2" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
        <CheckBox
                android:text="Checkbox1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/check1" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/apptheme_color"
                android:layout_weight="1"
        />
        <CheckBox
                android:text="Checkbox2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/check2" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/apptheme_color"
                android:layout_weight="1"
        />
        <Button
                android:text="Save"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textColor="#02485a" android:background="@drawable/blackborder"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>



</ScrollView>
```

Comment: you need to use scrollview for this. but main parent must be relative/linear layout

Comment: Ok, so how avoid situation, when scrollview extending height of my layout? When I use only linearlayout, layout looks the same on multiple screen sizes, but when I use scrollview, then it's much different.

Comment: post how you used scroll view in xml

Comment: <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
            />
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"

tl;dr -> relativelayout -> scrollview -> relative layout -> linearlayout

Comment: please post whole layout in your question

Comment: make inner relative layout match_parent for both width/height. and in menifest  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"

Comment: Not work :( maybe should I set scrollview as a root of my layout?

Comment: no do not make scrollview direct parent. i use same type of layout for signup screen and it is working perfectly

Comment: could you show screen shots of what happen when you use scrollview

Comment: Sorry but I can't do this

Comment: try to add fitsystemwindow=true in main parent relative layout

Answer (score 1):

Add `ScrollView` inside `RelativeLayout` with *fillViewport* property

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Yes, and it's expected behaviour `when I put as a root ScrollView, then my LinearLayout is bigger than screen size`

Comment: Yes, so main question is how prevent it.